# Looking for a +simple php framework for a rapid deployment

Tags: php, mobile, frameworks

I'm looking for a very, very simple php framework that has a simple mysql database class and routing built-in. A default style would be great. If it's geared toward html5 or mobile devices, perfect.

I know there are several out there, but I'd like to get the consensus.

Comment: self promotion: check out [tgsf](http://code.google.com/p/tgsf/)  not geared toward mobile specifically nor html5, but definitely quick to get up to speed with, and a nice PDO based query object.  you'd be best off grabbing the code from svn if you try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend you use CodeIgniter - it's not really all that small and probably has a few featured you don't need, but it's easiest to pick up I feel

In terms of the style/theme, I'd throw [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) in to the mix or alternatively, [Twitter's Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) (however Foundation has built-in responsive layout)

Comment: +1 for two really cool project links I've never heard of before. :)

Comment: Bootstrap is literally the coolest thing I've ever seen. I just made a mockup of my site layout in five minutes flat. Mind=blown. Thank you for sharing this...

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want a micro-framework.

[Flight](http://flightphp.com/) - a fast, simple, extensible micro-framework

[Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/) - a Sinatra clone in PHP

[FatFree](http://fatfree.sourceforge.net/) - a single file framework with lots of features

[Limonade](http://www.limonade-php.net/) - another framework inspired by Sinatra

[Klein](https://github.com/chriso/klein.php) - a lightning fast router for PHP

[Silex](http://silex-project.org/) - a micro-framework from the Symfony developers